# Model has no attribute 'DoesNotExists' in Manager

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Django 1.7 Exceptions documentation [exceptions.DoesNotExist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.DoesNotExist):

> The DoesNotExist exception is raised when an object is not found for
>   the given parameters of a query. Django provides a DoesNotExist
>   exception as an attribute of each model class to identify the class of
>   object that could not be found and to allow you to catch a particular
>   model class with try/except.

Based on above documentation I wrote custom Model Manager:

```
class CountryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_special(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'country': settings.ACTIVE_COUNTRY})
        try:
            return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
        except self.model.DoesNotExists:
            self.logger.warning('Unable to find specific object using filter {}'.format(kwargs))
            kwargs.update({'country': settings.DEFAULT_COUNTRY})
            return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
```

***Note that:*** *lines with `{'country': settings.ACTIVE_COUNTRY}` and with`{'country': settings.DEFAULT_COUNTRY}` are simplified for this example*

```
class CountryModelMixing(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        default=settings.DEFAULT_COUNTRY,
        choices=settings.COUNTRIES,
        verbose_name=_('country')
    )

    objects = CountryManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract=True


class Product(CountryModelMixing):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

and in code when I'm trying to:

```
Product.objects.get_special(name='abc')
```

And I'm getting following error:

```
/opt/src/common/managers.py in get_special(self, *args, **kwargs)
     40         try:
     41             return self.get(*args, **kwargs)
---> 42         except self.model.DoesNotExists:
     43             self.logger.warning('Unable to find specific object using filter {}'.format(kwargs))
AttributeError: type object 'Product' has no attribute 'DoesNotExists'
```

Comment: sorry my bad.. corrected

Comment: Try without an "s" at ``DoesNotExist``.

Comment: write this as an answer and I will approve it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DoesNotExist` does not take an "s":

```
except self.model.DoesNotExist:
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled the name of the exception:

```
except self.model.DoesNotExists:
#                             ^
```

The exception name is `DoesNotExist` without an `s` at the end.